# Source for shapefiles or geo-referenced data for Madhya Pradesh, India

Tags: shapefile, data, india

I am looking for data sources/shapefiles (demographics, cities, infrastructure, transportation, land cover, geology, etc.) for the state of Madhya Pradesh, India (specifically the Dewas or Khargone districts near Indore) and wondering if anyone has suggestions for good (re: free) sources for data for this region.

I am having difficulty downloading state from the state forest department (http://www.mpforest.org/intranet/gias/) and the MP GIS site doesn't seem to be free (http://www.nchse.org/mpgis/introduction.htm#.ViwBmCsYFSU).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the shapefiles from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) which contains various datasets:

[image: DIVA-GIS]

[image: Admin shapefile]

The *Administrative areas* shapefile contains the Dewas district which you can create a shapefile from. You could then **clip** or **intersect** shapefiles from other datasets to only show data for Dewas.

Hope this helps!